# IBM Bluemix node.js native promise support

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, containers, ibm-cloud

In my node.js application I use Promises very frequently. When working with the official node.js implementation V4 I don't have any problems. Node supports Promises since 0.13 natively.

When I switch to [IBM SDK for Node.js Version 4](https://developer.ibm.com/node/sdk/) thats contained in the IBMNode Docker container (FROM registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/ibmnode:latest) I get the following error when running my application:
`ReferenceError: Promise is not defined`

Why does IBM Node.js not support Promises natively and how can I enable native support without having to use a Promise npm package and refer to it in my code?

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile, please try setting `FROM ibmnode:v4` instead of `FROM ibmnode:latest`.  Although they should refer to the same version, it may be possible that you're somehow accidentally getting 0.12.x.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this will not work, cause ibmnode:lastet and ibmnode:4 point to the same image. So I will spare my time and will not test this.  

    `Image Id                             Created              Virt Size    Image Name`  
    *e65c0c2d613bd95b55024a5e2cc4e5fb88ed Feb  4 14:34:56 2016 434768132    registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/ibmnode:latest`  
    `e65c0c2d613bd95b55024a5e2cc4e5fb88ed Feb  4 14:34:56 2016 434768132    registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/ibmnode:v4`